# Why can't Swift infer this return type properly?

Tags: swift, type-inference

I'm trying to do something I think should be pretty simple, but I'm running into trouble with Swift's type inference. I really don't understand why it's falling down here.

I have a type `Cocktail`, which has other properties, but the only one important here is the `name`:

```swift
struct Cocktail {
    // ... other stuff
    let name: String
}
```

Then I have two protocols:

```swift
protocol ScrollIndexable {
    var scrollIndexTitle: String { get }
}

protocol ScrollIndexProviding {
    var scrollIndices: [any ScrollIndexable] { get }
}
```

along with a simple conformance on `String` to `ScrollIndexable`:

```swift
extension String: ScrollIndexable {
    var scrollIndexTitle: String { self }
}
```

I want to make it so that I can use an array of `Cocktail`s as a `ScrollIndexProviding`:

```swift
extension Array: ScrollIndexProviding where Element == Cocktail {
    var scrollIndices: [any ScrollIndexable] {
        let firstCharacters = reduce(into: Set<String>()) { partialResult, cocktail in
            guard let firstCharacter = cocktail.name.first else {
                return
            }
            partialResult.insert(String(firstCharacter))
        }
        // The return line here has two errors:
        // Cannot convert return expression of type 'Array<Cocktail>' to return type '[any ScrollIndexable]'
        // No exact matches in call to initializer
        return Array(firstCharacters)
    }
}
```

This extension fails to build, with two errors:

1. Cannot convert return expression of type 'Array' to return type '[any ScrollIndexable]'
2. No exact matches in call to initializer

The second error seems like noise to me, since `Set` conforms to `Sequence`, so I should be able to use that [init method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/init(_:)-236cl).

The first error is confusing to me since the `firstCharacters` array is of type `Set<String>`, so the error message just doesn't seem to make any sense. Is there something I'm misunderstanding about the `any` keyword here? What's going on?

Comment: If you know its an array of String can't you just return `[String]`? The extension then will apply at the usage site where it has the array. If String conforms to `ScrollIndexable` then all good. 

Comment: @Fogmeister yeah, I have fallen back on just declaring `ScrollIndexProviding` as just returning `[String]`, but I wanted to have this setup so that I could use different types for the `scrollIndexTitle` on `ScrollIndexable` (e.g. an image or icon rather than a String).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're inside an extension of `Array` where the `Element` is `Cocktail`, so when you try to create an array without specifying the element type the compiler will assume you mean for the element type to be `Cocktail`.

```swift
extension Array where Element: Cocktail {
    func someMethod() {

        // This array is of type `Array<Cocktail>` since the compiler 
        // assumes the array's element type should be the same as 
        // Self's element type, which (from the extension) is `Cocktail`.
        let array = Array()
    }
}
```

So, to fix this, just explicitly tell the compiler that the array's element type is String, as in:

```swift
extension Array: ScrollIndexProviding where Element == Cocktail {
    var scrollIndices: [any ScrollIndexable] {
        let firstCharacters = reduce(into: Set<String>()) { partialResult, cocktail in
            guard let firstCharacter = cocktail.name.first else {
                return
            }
            partialResult.insert(String(firstCharacter))
        }
        
        return Array<String>(firstCharacters)
        //          ^^^^^^^^ add this
    }
}
```